# Exporting hidden columns in materialui datagrid

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

is there anyway to hide a column in a materialui datagrid but also include it in exports? (Print, excel etc)

Comment: did u find a way?

Comment: Hey, I believe I just put hide:true in the columns I wanted hidden and exported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue as well. If you want the column to be hidden in the table view but appear in the export, define it like this:

```
{
    title: 'Column Title',
    field: 'field',
    hidden: true,
    export: true,
},
```

Comment: "hidden" doesn't exist on type GridColDef. Is this for an older version of MUI/DataGrid?